# random shuffle in RcppArrayFire

Tags: rcpp, arrayfire

I am experiencing trouble getting this example to run correctly.  Currently it produces the same random sample for every iteration and seed input, despite the seed changing as shown by af::getSeed().

```cpp
#include "RcppArrayFire.h"
#include <random>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppArrayFire;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
af::array random_test(RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f64> theta, int counts, int seed){

  const int theta_size = theta.dims()[0];

  af::array out(counts, theta_size, f64);

  for(int f = 0; f < counts; f++){

    af::randomEngine engine;
    af_set_seed(seed + f);
    //Rcpp::Rcout << af::getSeed();
    af::array out_temp = af::randu(theta_size, u8, engine);

    out(f, af::span) = out_temp;
    // out(f, af::span) = theta(out_temp);
  }
return out;
}


/*** R
theta <- 1:10
random_test(theta, 5, 1)
random_test(theta, 5, 2)
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are creating a random engine within each iteration of the loop but set the seed of the global random engine. Either you set the seed of the local engine via `engine.setSeed(seed)`, or you get rid of the local engine all together, letting `af::randu` default to using the global engine.

However, it would still be "unusual" to change the seed during each step of the loop. Normally one sets the seed only once, e.g.:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]
#include "RcppArrayFire.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
af::array random_test(RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f64> theta, int counts, int seed){

    const int theta_size = theta.dims()[0];

    af::array out(counts, theta_size, f64);
    af::setSeed(seed);

    for(int f = 0; f < counts; f++){

        af::array out_temp = af::randu(theta_size, u8);
        out(f, af::span) = out_temp;
    }
    return out;
}
```

BTW, it makes sense to parallelize this as long as your device has enough memory. For example, you could generate a random `counts x theta_size` matrix in one go using `af::randu(counts, theta_size, u8)`.

Comment: I noticed you removed the `#include <random>`. I too would have done the same but only because it isn't portable. Is that why you did it? Could you expound?

Comment: @JosephWood I try to include as few things as possible. In this case the `random` header isn't used, since ArrayFire comes with its own RNG.

Comment: implementation wise, on my non-example code, I am planing to parallelize the operation further up since I am optimizing over the shuffled data/residuals.  As of now I am doing this in the armadillo library